# Overriding jquery-ui with newer version on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a sharepoint site that has an old version of jquery ui (1.5.3) included in the head section of the master page.

I can't touch any of the master page code as I don't have access to it and I need to use the latested version of jquery ui in order for jCoverflip plugin to work.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the access problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)
It allows youto make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page.

Comment: Alas, jQuery *UI* does not support that feature.

Comment: That didn't work, but it did help me stumble upon the answer, which was to reference the latest version of jquery again and then reference the latest version of jquery-ui.